# Determine the $19$-th, $20$-th and $21$-st order Maclaurin polynomial for $f(x) = x\left(1-\cos{(2x^3)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Determine the $19$-th, $20$-th and $21$-st order Maclaurin polynomial for $f(x) = x\left(1-\cos{(2x^3)}\right)$.
We know that
\begin{equation*}
\cos{(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\ldots
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x\left(1-\cos{(2x^3)}\right)&= x\left(1-\left(1-\frac{4x^6}{2}+\frac{16x^{12}}{24}-\frac{64x^{18}}{720}+O(x^{24})\right)\right) \\
&= x\left(2x^6-\frac{2x^{12}}{3}+\frac{4x^{18}}{45}-O(x^{24})\right) \\
&= 2x^7-\frac{2x^{13}}{3}+\frac{4x^{19}}{45}-O(x^{25}).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Thus, the $19$-th, $20$-th and $21$-st order Maclaurin polynomial are all the same which are given by $2x^7-\frac{2x^{13}}{3}+\frac{4x^{19}}{45}$. Is this good?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: Great thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct and your calculations are valid. Since we have zero coefficients for terms $20, 21,22$  the polynomials of degree $19,20,21$ are all the same as the one with degree $19$